# Behringer UMC1820, signal detected even gain is on lowest level

Tags: audio

I bought Behringer UMC1820 yesterday. All is ok, but when I connect for example guitar to any input, signal is coming even when gain knob is on the lowest level. I think no signal should be coming if gain is down, or not?

Where is the catch? Sensibility of inputs? Some special configuration? Or luck on defective piece?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. How is the knob labelled? Typically a mic/line input gain trim gives low gain at minimum, but you still get a quiet signal. Then the label at minimum would be something like -20dB. This is different from a fader which goes down to nothing, and is labelled "-infinity" (a symbol like an 8 on its side; `-∞`). So what you are experiencing is probably as expected.